# How to prevent auto increment conflicts between branches?

Tags: mysql, sql, version-control, branch, auto-increment

Let's say I have the following schema and data on the `master` branch:

```
CREATE TABLE `account_roles` (
  `account_role_id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `position` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_role_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `position` (`position`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

INSERT INTO `account_roles` (`account_role_id`, `name`, `position`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Administrator', 1),
    (2, 'User', 2);
```

In our code we then check for an account's `account_role_id` to determine their role.

Now let's say we create two branches of `master` for two new pieces of functionality, both of which require a new account role. Each branch will insert a new record into the `account_roles` table like so:

`moderators` branch:

```
INSERT INTO `account_roles` (`account_role_id`, `name`, `position`)
    VALUES (NULL, 'Moderator', '3');
```

`sponsors` branch:

```
INSERT INTO `account_roles` (`account_role_id`, `name`, `position`)
    VALUES (NULL, 'Sponsor', '3');
```

The `moderators` branch now has a Moderator role with an `account_role_id` of 3 and the `sponsors` branch now has a Sponsor role with an `account_role_id` of 3, each checking for an `account_role_id` of 3 when checking to see if an account is a Moderator/Sponsor. Obviously this is going to cause a conflict when they are merged.

What are the solutions to resolve this? The two I can think of are:

1. Merge and then update the code to check against the correct `account_role_id` after the database migration queries have been run.
2. Add a unique `code` column (based on the name and which should hopefully never conflict) that we query against to retrieve the correct `account_role_id`.

Comment: Well, only if sponsor/moderator are not part of the primary key

Comment: I have no idea what the `position` column is used for.  It seems superfluous.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, that's just to order the account roles in lists/dropdowns. Not relevant for the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing about active SQL schemas and other DBMS code: they know nothing about source-control branches.

So, once you have an active database, you cannot deploy a new version by deploying a changed `CREATE TABLE` statement: it recreates a new empty table from scratch.

To change the definition of an existing table, for example to add a row, you need to deploy the change with an `ALTER TABLE` statement. In that case the existing rows keep their auto incrementing `id` column values, and any new rows get new values.

In most cases losing the contents of a table is a disaster. But, you may have some very small reference tables that you can recreate from scratch each time you release a new version.

Wise devs write SQL code to update their schemas, then test that code on private, development, and staging database instances. Then, the script gets run once on the production database at the time of deployment to production.